# my .find function is not matching the id of data.js with id that user is inputing

Tags: reactjs

I want my find function to match the id of data.js with id of the product that user clicked so that i can go to the specific details of product user clicked. But when i add the .find function it says error with cannot read property image of undefined.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import ProductScreen from './screens/ProductScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import AppFront from './appfront/AppFront';

function App(){
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
        <main>
          <Route path='/' component={AppFront} exact />
          <Route path='/' component={HomeScreen} exact />
          <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} />
        </main>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default App
```

And my ProductScreen code

```
import React from 'react'
import Rating from '../components/Rating';
import data from '../data'

function ProductScreen(props) {
    const product = data.products.find(x => x._id === props.match.params.id)
    // if(!product){
    //     return <div>Product not available</div>
    // }
    return (
        <div className='product-container'>
           <div className='product-img'>
               <img src={product.image} alt={product.title} />
           </div>
           <div className='product-details'>
               <h3>{product.title}</h3>
               <Rating rating={product.rating} numReviews={product.numReviews}/>
               <p>{product.numReviews}</p>
               <h2>Rs. {product.price}</h2>
               <div className='btn-product-container'>
                   <button className='btn'>Buy Now</button>
                   <button className='btn'>Add to Cart</button>
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

Comment: You should probably wrap `ProductScreen` with `withRouter` - https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter

Comment: `cannot read property image of undefined` because of `{product.image}`.  `product` is undefined because `data.products.find(x => x._id === props.match.params.id)` didn't find anything in `products` with `_id` equal to `props.match.params.id`.

Comment: you mean i should wrap this <Route path="/product/:id" component={ProductScreen} /> with withRouter??

Comment: No. `export default withRouter(ProductScreen)` instead of `export default ProductScreen`

Comment: Yes why it dint find anything at all. Thats my question. i have array products with _id property in data.js. Still  its saying its undefined. Is my function wrong??

Comment: got same error mosh :(

Comment: The function is fine. If I'm right, `props.match.params.id` should throw an error or it's `undefined`. Try to `console.log(props.match.params.id)`

Comment: Cannot ready property of match. I think the props is not being passed down from app level component

Comment: `match` is a special prop being injected by react-router-dom only if you wrap your component with `withRouter`. This is why I suggested this change.

Comment: so i console logged the props.id part so its saying its undefined. So is my props from the app level state not being passed down to the component through route

Comment: Have you tried to wrap the component with `withRouter`?

Comment: Yes i did wraped the export default withRouter(ProductScreen)

Comment: And the url is `/product/8` but `props.match.params.id` is undefined?

Comment: Yes if i go to the first product the url is /product/1 but the i consoled the id and the id is returning undefined

Comment: It should work. See my example (it's not exactly your code but it demonstrate the same intent) - https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-gates-rynn8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Yes i also dont see any errors to happen. I have got everything right when i click the link there is id at the back of url but i dont know why the id is not being passed down to the prop and its getting undefined . This is insanely making me crazy

Comment: Nyway Mosh dude thanks for staying until now and helping me. U are great bro. Keep it up. I will wipe clean and do it from start and try to find the bug. Thanks bro